# How do you check that if an intent has finished working?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to update an apk through code. However I need to establish a mechanism that checks when that application has updated. I need to somehow get a message back from the intent

```
Context ctx = getApplicationCOntext();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

This is the default mechanism to install an application. How can I check that if the intent has finished?

Comment: Can you add a method in the launcher activity? You could pass an extra with the intent, receive it in the launcher activity, and do your task from there..

Comment: No I can't. A service initiates this method

Comment: How about returning from the listening to the logs regarding the successful installation of the target apk to flag the task status?

Comment: How can I implement that in code?

Comment: ctx.startActivityForResult and override on activity result method

Answer (score 1):

Use `startActivityForResult()` if you want data to be return from the called activity.
 For more details, read: 
 [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)  
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)